# is there any way catch longclick leave or end event in android

Tags: java, android

when i use longclick on a button it opens a Dialogbox and when release my press(longclickend ) from the button..it should come back to my first view......

Answer (score 0):

btw, i don't really know what you are asking. Be more descriptive and explain what you've already tried. Also, as dziobas said, if you find someone answered your question, accept their answer so others are more inclined to answer your questions.

but here are two comments:

1) if you don't return true after the longclick event, i believe the onclick event will be triggered (i think).

2) it sounds like maybe you should be considering just starting an activity for result.